# How to move an SVN repository from one server to another

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svnserve, svn-repository

I need to copy the existing SVN repository from one development server to another. Per my understandings, I have come up with the steps. It would be great if someone can verify and let me know if I have missed any point.

```
Current server: dev10.dev.location.somename.com
Current repo location: dev10$/export/svnrepo/reponame
URL: svn:// dev10.dev.location.somename.com/export/svnrepo/newrepo/trunk

New server: dev11.dev.location.somename.com
New repo location: dev11$/export/svnrepo/newrepo
```

I would like to have a URL like svn://dev11.dev.location.somename.com/export/svnrepo/newrepo/trunk. Do I need to import the new repository?

```
SVN server --- **svnserve**
```

Steps:

1. Install svnserve server in dev11
2. Check working directory is fully checked-in at dev10 to Subversion, and back it up.
3. Dump the Subversion repository. This is done with an `svnadmin` command: at dev10

   ```
   svnadmin dump /export/svnrepo/reponame | gzip -9 - > reponame.dump.gz
   ```
4. Create the new subversion repository ---- at dev11. To create a repository, ‘newrepo’, run the `svnadmin create` command from $SVNHOME/bin. Provide fullpath to the repository at dev11.

   ```
   svnadmin create /export/svnrepo/newrepo
   ```
5. Copy the reponame.dump.gz file up to the dev11 server.
6. Load the dumpfile into the new repository: at dev11

   ```
   zcat reponame.dump.gz | svnadmin load /export/svnrepo/newrepo
   ```
7. Checkout the new repository to a directory at dev11

   ```
   svn co svn:// dev11.dev.location.somename.com/export/svnrepo/newrepo/trunk
   ```
8. Switch my working directory to the new repository.

Comment: Aah, my steps were correct. I just executed them. Thanks